# Move color channels and spot colour channel at the same time?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, spot-color, channel

when I select part of my image layer and move it with the move tool, the colour channels move as expected but the graphic on the spot color channel stays where it is. I have to go back and select the spot color channel and redo the move which destroys the placement accuracy of the logo relative to the colour background. Anyway to move all channels together at the same time? Thx, JK

[image]

Comment: Why are you using Photoshop to make a logo?  I honestly think you'd have much less trouble using a vector image editor. Each object could then have its own fill, and then you wouldn't have to worry about channels at all.

Answer (score 0):

No way of doing that in Photoshop, unfortunately.

A workaround would be:

1. create a temp channel from your selection to store it;
2. move your pixels with `Free Transform` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>);
3. load your temp channel as selection and select the spot channel;
4. use `Edit > Transform > Again` menu command (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to move the selection of the channel to the same distance as in 2);

Comment: Thank you Sergey. Will test it. Not making a logo - I'm moving a selection that includes a logo and files were supplied. thanks.